# Duplicate structures and substructures simultaneously

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My aim is to use XSLT 1.0 to transform an XML file so that it duplicates specific nodes. The problem is, that I need to duplicate substructures of structures that also need to be duplicated.

Here the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent_node>
    <derived_from_a>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
    </derived_from_a>
    <derived_from_b>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
        <derived_from_c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </derived_from_c>
    </derived_from_b>
</parent_node>
```

I need all the `<derived_from_a>` nodes to be duplicated into a new node with the name `<a>`. The same should happen with the nodes `<derived_from_b>` and `<derived_from_c>` for the new nodes `<b>` and `<c>`.

This is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent_node>
    <derived_from_a>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
    </derived_from_a>
    <a>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
    </a>
    <derived_from_b>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
        <derived_from_c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </derived_from_c>
        <c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </c>
    </derived_from_b>
    <b>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
        <derived_from_c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </derived_from_c>
        <c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </c>
    </b>
</parent_node>
```

Note that I am duplicating the node `<derived_from_c>` into `<c>` in both parent structures (`<derived_from_b>` and `<b>`). That is what I need.

I wrote the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- -->
    <xsl:template match="//derived_from_a">
        <!-- first copy structure with original name -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!-- then duplicate it -->
        <a>
            <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//derived_from_b">
        <!-- first copy structure with original name -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!-- then duplicate it -->
        <b>
            <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()"/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//derived_from_c">
        <!-- first copy structure with original name -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!-- then duplicate it -->
        <c>
            <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()"/>
        </c>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This generates this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent_node>
    <derived_from_a>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
    </derived_from_a>
    <a>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
    </a>
    <derived_from_b>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
        <derived_from_c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </derived_from_c>
        <c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </c>
    </derived_from_b>
    <b>
        <element1>test</element1>
        <element2>test</element2>
        <derived_from_c>
            <element3>test</element3>
            <element4>test</element4>
        </derived_from_c>
    </b>
</parent_node>
```

Note that the node `<c>` only exists in the node `<derived_from_b>`. Not in the node `<b>`.
I have tried moving the `<derived_from_c>` transformation to the top of my XSLT without success.

Is there a way I can duplicate everything in one mapping?

Comment: `<xsl:template match="//derived_from_a">` - note that it's not necessary to anchor your match expressions. Writing this as `<xsl:template match="derived_from_a">` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 transformation gives the result you are looking for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'derived_from_')]">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    <xsl:element name="{substring-after(name(), 'derived_from_')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

namely

```
<parent_node>
  <derived_from_a>
    <element1>test</element1>
    <element2>test</element2>
  </derived_from_a>
  <a>
    <element1>test</element1>
    <element2>test</element2>
  </a>
  <derived_from_b>
    <element1>test</element1>
    <element2>test</element2>
    <derived_from_c>
      <element3>test</element3>
      <element4>test</element4>
    </derived_from_c>
  </derived_from_b>
  <b>
    <element1>test</element1>
    <element2>test</element2>
    <derived_from_c>
      <element3>test</element3>
      <element4>test</element4>
    </derived_from_c>
    <c>
      <element3>test</element3>
      <element4>test</element4>
    </c>
  </b>
</parent_node>
```

The trick here is to give the identity template both a `match` and a `name`. This way it can be invoked both "pull-style" by the XSLT processor as it traverses your input document, and manually through `<xsl:call-template>`.

The manual invoke enables us to process the descendants of the current node instead of just copying them, which addresses your requirement *"to duplicate substructures of structures that also need to be duplicated."*

---

If your output element names (`<a>`) are not actually substrings of your input element names (`<derived_from_a>`), you could be tempted to duplicate the worker template.

In order to avoid that duplication, you could embed a mapping into your XSLT in a custom element, and use a self-reference via `document('')` to pull out the new name dynamically:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:my="http://tempuri.org"
>
  <my:map>
    <name from="derived_from_a" to="x" />
    <name from="derived_from_b" to="y" />
    <name from="derived_from_c" to="z" />
  </my:map>

  <!-- ... -->
   
  <xsl:template match="derived_from_a|derived_from_b|derived_from_c">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:element name="{document('')/*/my:map/name[@from = name(current())]/@to}">
      <!-- ... -->
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Adding configuration with custom elements can be quite useful at times. Another option would be to pass in the mapping through an `<xsl:param>` from the calling code, depending on the capabilities of the XSLT tooling you're using. The third option would be to use an `<xsl:variable>` containing an `<xsl:choose>` to determine the new element name.

Comment: @nikiforos6 Good to hear! Also see the suggestion I've just added.